# Adding ifcondition in componentdidupdate in react but then also infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a link tag I am sending it to same component but with different parameter. For that I am using componentdidupdate .If I would have used anchor tag then it was not required. I added a if condition in componentdidupdate and then a url request and setting the state but getting infinite loop. Infinite request going to server
Code of link

```
Link to={`/tutorials/${id}/${courseid}`}>{title}</Link>
```

In componentdidupdate

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
if (this.props.params.id !== prevState.id ) {
  const { id } = this.props.params;
  const { courseid } = this.props.params;
  let url = `https://localhost:7058/Dashboard/api/Tutorial?ID=${courseid}`;
  this.setState({
    loading: true,
  });
  let data = await fetch(url);
  let parsedData = await data.json();
  this.setState({
    lectures: parsedData,
    courseid: courseid,
    id: id,
    loading: false,
  });
  //now api request for description
  let durl = `https://localhost:7058/Dashboard/api/Tutorial/GetTutorial?ID=${courseid}&TutorialID=${id}`;
  this.setState({
    loading: true,
  });
  let ddata = await fetch(durl);
  let dparsedData = await ddata.json();
  // console.log(dparsedData);
  this.setState({
    desc: dparsedData,
    loading: false,
  });
}
```

}

```
export default (props) => <Tutorial {...props} params={useParams()} />;
```

I am using react 18 and react router dom 6. Provide solution for this version , please don't suggest either to degrade version or change it to function based component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the condition is malformed, you likely want to compare against `prevProps.params.id`, or maybe `this.state.id` since it would have been updated on a previous render cycle.

Example:

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if (this.props.params.id !== prevProps.params.id ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

or

```
async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  if (this.props.params.id !== this.state.id ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks: prevProps one working. Actually I also checked from official docs it was showing prevProps.id so, I tried that but it was not working

Comment: @Anonymous Welcome. Just curious, what docs are you referring to?

Comment: React official docs. Might be they haven't updated it: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @Anonymous Oh, I see. Looks like a minor misunderstanding. In your component the prop is `params`, both in the previous render cycle and the current render cycle. In the example in the docs, the prop was `userID`. The `params` prop updated, but you want the stronger condition of checking the `id` property. Anyway, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Understood. Just wanted to know do you have any experience in jquery . If yes, can u look into this question as well, not getting solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71723561/form-fields-are-not-serializing-in-jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-form-data-not-updati

Comment: @Anonymous I know enough to steer clear of it, but I can take a look. ...and yeah, I think it's a bit beyond any experience I have, sorry.